# Why Aren't the router.events Firing for FooComponent in My Angular Application?

Tags: javascript, angular

When I access the link https://stackblitz-starters-cg5qqn.stackblitz.io/bar/1, I can't find the eventsFromFoo entries in the console.

It seems that `this.router.events` isn't triggering for `FooComponent`.

Do you know why this is happening? I need to capture that router event. Do you have any suggestions for a fix?

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cg5qqn)

```
@Component({
  selector: `bar`,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule],
  template: `bar works <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class BarComponent {
  router = inject(Router);
  route = inject(ActivatedRoute);

  constructor() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(paramsFromBar => {
      console.log({ paramsFromBar });
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe(eventsFromBar => {
      console.log({ eventsFromBar });
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: `foo`,
  standalone: true,
  template: `foo works`,
})
export class FooComponent {
  router = inject(Router);
  route = inject(ActivatedRoute);

  constructor() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(paramsFromFoo => {
      console.log({ paramsFromFoo });
    });
    this.router.events.subscribe(eventsFromFoo => {
      console.log({ eventsFromFoo });
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  template: `....
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App { ... }

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'bar',
        component: BarComponent,
        children: [{ path: ':id', component: FooComponent }],
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

So, when visiting `/bar/1`, I expect to see the router event trigger, as shown in line 47: `console.log({ eventsFromFoo });`.

However, it doesn't seem to work. I'm curious why, especially considering `FooComponent` is a child route of `BarComponent` using `<router-outlet>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no event on the router once `FooComponent` is instantiated.

They all happen after the call to the constructor.

I would log for example if you left that `foo/1` route to go to `/` for example !